# Elasticsearch add data with Nodejs

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

I'm creating app with NodeJs and PostgreSQL and I whant to add ElasticSearch for it
But I don't realize

- how add new data to ElasticSearch
- how sync my data from PostgreSQL to ElasticSearch

Can someone help me? How add data to ElasticSearch and how sync my data between ElasticSearch and PostgreSQL? Thnq :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Adding data to ElasticSearch is done by `PUT`ing documents (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html)
- Syncing data between postgres and ElasticSearch is a more complicated task. Assuming the data in the postgres tables change, you would need to mark what you indexed in ElasticSearch as `indexed` or `processed`, then continue processing. If tuples have a timestamp or incremental ids, then you can process tuples after indexing timestamp or `last_processed_id`.

You can run a `cron job` to keep syncing/updating your ElasticSearch indexes, or you can go fancy and write custom triggers in postgres that inserts/updates ElasticSearch documents.

I, personally, would go for triggers since data will be updated/inserted instantly in the ElasticSearch indexes.